# Django Form, User input fields not rendering in template

Tags: python, django, forms

Django newb here, but I'm learning.

**Problem Statement**

Input fields not rendering in html template.

**Output in Browser**

True

| Submit Button |

**Relevant Code**

```
forms.py
from django import forms
from django.db import models

class PostNotes(forms.Form):
    clientid = models.IntegerField()
    notetext = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

-

```
views.py
def post_form_notes(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        sawit = True
        form = PostNotes(initial={'notetext':'This is a sample note'})
    else:
        sawit = False
        pass
    return render(request, 'clientadmin/post_form_notes.html', {
        'form': form,
        'sawit': sawit,
    })
```

-

```
post_form_notes.html
{{ sawit }}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Troubleshooting Already Done**

- I have backed out a fair amount of the code (specifically if I see a
  POST) request from the browser.  No change.
- I have also included a variable to ensure I am seeing the GET request and also the template variables are working.  I get output of True.
- Simplified the Form Class as much as possible.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for your reply, and I think you are correct in what is happening.  I create an object and pass it to the template.  I believe, the |as_p filter is supposed to convert it to the representative objects from the object.  However, as it is not working, I am certainly not sure this is right.  Followed (more or less) this example.  http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-python-django-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I modified the forms.py to use the model I already had for the DB.

**forms.py:**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from clientadmin.models import notes

class PostNotes(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = notes
        fields = ['notedate', 'notetext']
```

I also modified the views.py to not set an initial value, so the function uses the following instead of what was asked.

**models.py:**

```
def post_form_notes(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostNotes()
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'clientadmin/post_form_notes.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Hope this helps someone that was having the same problem I was...

Reference the following URL for further information:   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/